# how to put a breakpoint on function defined in a .so file which is called via verilog pli interface

Tags: gdb, verilog

I am working on testbench environment where I need to debug a segmentation fault during rtl simulation on a call to a pli routine. This pli routine is defined in a `.so` file say `routines.so` which is linked to the simulation executable  produced after vcs compilation of design and testbench environment. Let me say simulator executable is named `simv`. Say the function that i want to break at `C side` is `badfunction()`, this is called in verilog side as `$badfunction()`. I have compiled `routines.so` with debug support.

I have attached gdb to the vcs `simv` simulator executable that is running my simulation and i do see `routines.so` loaded and symbols read from it. I check this by running `info shared`.

Now I look for the symbol `badfunction` like this `info address badfunction`. I get message like this. 
`Symbol "badfunction" is at 0x156bea0 in a file compiled without debugging`
This is what got me thinking that putting breakpoint at `badfunction` might not get me to correct place. So I check which `badfunction` it is referring to `info symbol 0x156bea0`. This gives me the message `badfunction in section .text of  /home/simulations/rtl/build/simv`.  So it is referring to `badfunction` in `simv`.

I need to be sure that i put breakpoint at correct place as it take about 10 hours for simulation to reach point of failure. How do I  put the breakpoint at the `badfunction` in the `routines.so`? 
The function name `badfunction` is not mangled. I can see the symbol on disassembling `routines.so`. How do i tell gdb to look for the function in `routines.so`?

Comment: I don't believe you can put a break point in an `.so` file. It been a while since I attempted, but I believe you can compile vcs with the source files of `routines.so`, that may allow you to use break points for the pli.

Comment: @Greg I am not sure it is equivalent to put breakpoint on `.so` file but i think it is something close.  I used `info function badfunction` which gave me all the address of symbols which looked like `badfunction`. I followed it up with `info symbol <address>` where `address` was obtained in first step. This provided me with information about in which file symbol is defined.  This way i was sure which address I had to put breakpoint say it was `0xpreferred_address`. Now I had to do `break *0xpreferred_address` and I had breakpoint at correct place in `.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with gdb 7.4, in response to `break function`, gdb will set a breakpoint at all matching functions.  So, `break badfunction` ought to do what you want.

However, since it takes 10 hours to get to the spot you want to debug, there are a couple of things you can do first to ensure that the right thing is happening.

First, make sure your .so has debuginfo.  The most reliable way to do this is to directly examine the .so that will be loaded (that is, if it's installed somewhere, check the installed copy, not your development copy) using `objdump` or `readelf`.  I usually just do `readelf -wi whatever.so`; if it dumps a lot of stuff, then you have debuginfo.

Next, you can check to verify that the breakpoint is set correctly.  If the .so is linked in to the executable, then this is easy:

```
$ gdb whatever
(gdb) break badfunction
(gdb) start
```

At this point, all the linked-in shared libraries will have been loaded and you can do this:

```
(gdb) info break
```

... and examine the resulting breakpoints for sanity.  I'd imagine, based on what you said above, that `badfunction` should have two locations set.

If the .so is not linked into the resulting executable (sounds that way but I don't really know), then it's a bit more complicated.  One approach is to do `catch load`, then `continue` until you reach the spot where the desired library is loaded, and breakpoints are re-resolved in gdb.  Then examine them as above.

Comment: Yes what you mentioned worked. In fact I had seen this happen before and I didn't think of trying it out. I paste a few lines for reference for some one.  All i had to do is disable the not required breakpoint.                                                                                              `2.1                         n     0x000000000152ec10 <badfunction>                                
2.2                         y     0x00007ffe89909070 <badfunction>`  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: There is one other thing that I tried and worked. I used `info function badfunction` which gave me all the address of symbols which looked like `badfunction`. I followed it up with `info symbol <address>` where `address` was obtained in first step. This provided me with information about in which file symbol is defined.  This way i was sure which address I had to put breakpoint.